# How can I add/integrate a general site comment to my existing commenting system in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have got a commenting system something like below. User can comment articles, images and posts. Everything works fine. But additional to this I want to add a section where the user can comment the website itself, something like a general comment. I want to integrate this to the existing commenting system. But naturally there is no table or model for the site itself where I could add a relationship. What would be a good way to go?

tables are like:

```
articles
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

images
    id - integer
    title - integer
    path - text

comments
    id - integer
    comment - text
    commentable - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

and models are something like:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}

class Images extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}

class Article extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have possibly a `users` table, then maybe its time to add comments relationship to the `User` model? i.e be part of the commentables too Just thinking of ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one site you can set your morph fields to be nullable and add a scope to your `Comment` model that would return only those comments which are related to your site, like this:

```
public function scopeForWebsite($query) {
    return $query->where(function($query) {
        $query->whereNull('commentable')->whereNull('commentable_type');
    });
}
```

and then retrieve your website comments using:

`Comment::forWebsite()->get()`

When creating comment just don't attach it to any entity and it will be treated as a global, generic one.

Just remember that you will need to manually add `commentable` and `commentable_type` fields in your migration (instead of assumed `$table->morphs('commentable')`), mark them as nullable and index those fields.

Comment: you are completely right. I definitely will use that. But why "index those fields" ? Did you say that for (generic) speeding up the table or for another reason?

Comment: Laravel automatically indexes morph fields when calling `$table->morphs(...);`, but if you are adding those manually you need to add index on your own. If you don't you will suffer performance issues when using eager loading (ex. `Article::with('comments')->all()` )